# SSRS ReportViewer Control linked report does not start at top

Tags: ssrs-2008

I am using an SSRS ReportViewer Control (2008) On a web form to display an SSRS Report. The SSRS Report has links to many other SSRS reports. When I click on one of the linked reports, I get unwanted behavior.

Instead of the top of the report being visible as I would expect, the report starts out at the bottom. The scrollbar on the right in the browser window is at the very bottom, and I need to scroll up to view the top of the report.

I don't want my users to have to scroll up every time they navigate to a new report. Is there a way I can force the report start at the top? (So the scrollbar on the right hand starts at the top)

I do not see this behavior when I am previewing the report in Visual Studio 2008.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

which browser are you using? I know that Chrome does not Support report manager for example (the reports are cut in half).

Take a look at this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251673.aspx) and this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252090.aspx), they may help you.